# Insert an empty column with a step by 7 in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 28 columns, but after every 7 columns I want to insert an empty column. Can you help me to create that macro.

[image: Initial Columns]

[image: After Macro]

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "LP"
    For i = 2 To 22
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Sheets(i).Cells(5, 2).Select
        Sheets(i).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Linearity Plot").Activate
        Sheets("Linearity Plot").Cells(i - 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(21, 121)).Select

ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Transpose"
    Sheets("Transpose").Activate

Worksheets("LP").Range("A1:DQ21").Copy
Worksheets("Transpose").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: I have 21/28/35.. sheets with information in every sheet from A1 to DQ. I manage to create a macro which take the information from all of these sheets and put in another sheet and also to transpose this information. I will edit the question to see what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Sub insertColumns()
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = 28
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim nbColAdded As Integer
    nbColAdded = 0

    While i < lastCol + nbColAdded
        i = i + 8
        nbColAdded = nbColAdded + 1
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Insert
    Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: And If I want to add 2 empty columns, where have I to modify? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When inserting or deleting rows or columns in a loop, it is considered best practise to start at the outer boundary and work in. For rows, this means start at the bottom and work up; columns you would start at the right-most and work toward the left. This method avoids the renumbering effect that inserting or deleting rows/columns has on the remainder of the rows/columns to be processed.

Since you want to insert one or more columns every *x* number of columns, you will have to know how many columns you have to start with and determine whether that is a multiple of *x*. If it is not, you may have to shift right or left before commencing the insert columns loop.

According to your original question, you have 28 columns and the *stagger* is 'after every 7th column'. I take this as wanting to insert one or more columns at the 29th, 22nd, 15th and 8th position. After repositioning from the insertion of the other columns, the new pairs of columns will be in H:I, Q:R and Z:AA.

```
Sub insert_columns()
    Dim iStagger As Long, iNumCols As Long, c As Long, lc As Long

    iStagger = 7
    iNumCols = 2
    With ActiveSheet
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lc = lc + 8 - (lc Mod iStagger)
        For c = lc To iStagger Step -iStagger
            .Cells(1, c).Resize(1, iNumCols).EntireColumn.Insert
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Modify the stagger and/or the number of columns to insert in the 3rd and 4th row. Everything else should be taken care of with the calculations.